# Ruby Timeout behaves differently between 2.0 and 2.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, ruby-2.1

The following code behaves differently between ruby 2.0 and 2.1:

```
require 'timeout'

def scp
  begin
    puts "In begin"
    sleep 10
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Exception found: #{e}"
  else
    puts "No exception found"
  ensure
    puts "In ensure"
  end
end

Timeout::timeout(1) do
  scp
end
```

In ruby 2.0, it gives:

```
In begin
Exception found: execution expired
In ensure
```

In ruby 2.1, it gives:

```
In begin
In ensure
t2.rb:7:in `sleep': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
    from t2.rb:7:in `scp'
    from t2.rb:18:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `block in catch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:106:in `timeout'
    from t2.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Why are they different?

Comment: I'm testing out Ruby 2.2.3 on Linux and I get the same behavior as your Ruby 2.1.  I also see that `Timeout::Error.new.is_a?(Exception)` equals true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented behavior.  We can compare the documentation of Ruby's Timeout module for [2.0.0](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) and for [2.1.0](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html).  The documentation for 2.1.0 says:

> The exception thrown to terminate the given block cannot be rescued inside the block unless klass is given explicitly.

If you want to have the old behavior in your application, you can call `Timeout::timeout(1, Timeout::Error)`.  This would allow you to catch the exception inside the timed block.

Comment: How odd. This change wasn't commented upon much. I am not sure it actually helps much. I am curious to see if latest JRuby 9k has 2.1.0 behavior...